# Google Script to clear Checkboxes and Notes in cells unexpectedly clears HYPERLINKS as well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:** Clear all cell notes and checkboxes (convert Checkboxes from TRUE to FALSE)

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOR:**  Clears all cell notes, checkboxes, and hyperlinks.  It leaves behind text formatted to appear like a hyperlink... but no actual link.

Before:

[image]

After (only text & formatting remains -- link is gone)

[image]

```
function ResetCheckBoxesAndClearNotesOnDefinedSheets(){
  var tabs = [
    'Checkout',
    'Reception'
  ];

  //LOOP THROUGH TABS LISTED ABOVE
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  for (var k = 0; k < tabs.length; k++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[k]);
    //CLEAR NOTES ON TABS LISTED ABOVE    
    sheet.clearNotes();  

    // CLEAR CHECKBOXES ON TABS LISTED ABOVE
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        if (values[i][j] === true) {
          values[i][j] = false; // Modified
        }
      }
    }

    dataRange.setValues(values);
  }//end of  sheets loop.
}
```

***How do I stop the removal of hyperlinks?***

Comment: If you are going to write values, note that you will remove **all** formulas from the written range as well. So either [replace values with formulas where present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775843/9337071), or [only write `false` to checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890279/how-to-have-only-one-box-checked-instead-of-two-on-google-apps-script/51898268#51898268).

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on how to only write false to checkboxes?  Oops-- looking at the hyperlinks in your comment now. Thanks! Will try to figure it out

Comment: I figure out how to get the FORMULAS to stay, and checkboxes to reset, notes to clear... but now all of the non-formula text clears.


var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
var values = dataRange.getValues();
var formulas = dataRange.getFormulas(); 
         
for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < formulas[i].length; j++) {
    if (formulas[i][j] === true) {
      formulas[i][j] = false; // Modified
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(formulas);



Admittedly, I don't understand what's going on w the array.

Comment: You might find my Q&A here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935257/finding-all-checkboxes-in-a-google-sheet

Comment: Thanks -- is there a way to do this without using the Google API Cloud Platform?

To only find checkboxes that are checked, and uncheck them, while leaving the formulas in tact?

Comment: If you're using Google Apps Script and Google Sheets you're using Google Cloud Platform already. And my answer there demonstrates checkboxes with both Spreadsheet Service and Sheets API...

Comment: Thanks -- I tried Spreadsheet Service script at the link above. I get error about Sheets not being defined.  There is a comment that says // Enable before use... but I'm not sure what that is referring to...

Comment: As mentioned in the text of the answer, that means you have to enable the advanced service. A link was given. An internet search will also lead you to the relevant official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the script in the links. THANKS!

```
function ResetCheckboxesOnSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getDataValidations();
  var cbA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      var rule=vA[i][j];
      if(rule!=null) {
        var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
        if(criteria == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
          sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).setValue(false)

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that, as mentioned in the link, this code here only works for the specific type of checkbox that has the literal `true` and `false` as the checked/unchecked values. Checkboxes can have *any* value for these properties, such as "Yes" and "No", "Y" and "N", "Running" and "Paused", 1 and 0, and so on.

Comment: I running this on [clicking a RESET button](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/) and it is a good-enough combination for a simple checklist. Thanks!